# Which is best framework for saas project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, grails, playframework, saas

We are building a new SAAS bussiness application and we are looking for some advice .

what is the best suitable framework to do this job ? We have big experience in C# .
but we do't need to take ASP.Net MVC because it's very expensive, We want to run in linux
based hosting with postgresql database.

In your opinion which framework fits well to do this job .

Django , Play framework , Rails or Grails ?

Comment: Hi! This question would be better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ since it is a concept question rather a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always recommend Django.  I run [www.noobmovies.com](http://www.noobmovies.com) on Linode for about 20.00 a month.  The site gets thousands of visitors a week and I just got started.  I don't come near to exceeding 5% of my available resources.  I am a .NET developer during the day, so I too use C#.

C# ASP.NET is not an option to me at all.  As a small business owner I'm much better off with Django.  It does everything I need and when I compare my current resources I receive using Linode over .NET I'm looking at a 600 to 700 monthly difference easy.  If I compare to Azure It's probably a thousand dollar difference.

Granted my site is using MySQL Postgresql is easy to configure with Django.